# tornado.httpclient.HTTPError: HTTP 599: Timeout in request queue issue

Tags: tornado

I'm using the Tornado's Async http client to create a async barrier library using etcd. I want to change the timeout of the fetch http requests to greater than the default of 20s. I used the request_timeout=120 and connect_timeout=120 to increase the timeouts related to the fetches. However I still get tornado throwing an exception after the default 20s:

```
tornado.httpclient.HTTPError: HTTP 599: Timeout in request queue
ERROR:tornado.access:500 GET /a (::1) 22684.49ms
```

I did read where Ben mentioned there is a bug as at Jul 2:

https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/1753

however I thought that increasing both the connection and request timeouts would have fixed this? Is this still an outstanding bug? As the latest release is Oct 1, 2016

Comment: Are you sending a lot of concurrent requests? The timeout is actually from the time the request is queued, not from the time it's initiated. If `SimpleHTTPClient`'s default concurrency level of 20 is not enough, your requests will time out while waiting to be sent.

Comment: Hi Blender, yes I am sending lots of simultaneous requests i increased the max_clients, i think that was part of the issue. But i still don't think the request_timeout parameter is working as it should.

Comment: Can you show how exactly you're setting the timeouts? The queue timeout should be using request_timeout and connect_timeout (whichever is shorter), so if you're setting both to 120 you shouldn't get a timeout after 22 seconds.

Comment: Hi Ben, the line of code was simply to set the request_timeout in the HTTPRequest class: HTTPRequest(url=url+"?wait=true",method="GET",request_timeout=timeout) I removed the connection_timeout line. This was followed by a fetch: request=await self.httpClient.fetch(waitRequest). However it might not be an issue anymore since I updated my max_clients. I think this was the main source of my problems. Because I was performing locks I was maxing out the clients and this was causing new fetches to wait for the lock to be release and the old locks weren't able to make new fetches to release.

Comment: I'll need to check again however i still think the clients were timing out after the default 20seconds rather than the request_timeout i passed. Could it be that when max_clients is full the request_timeout is set to the default?

Answer (score 2):

For `SimpleHTTPClient`, time spent in the request queue is still counted against the timeouts. Your error message says just that:

```
tornado.httpclient.HTTPError: HTTP 599: Timeout in request queue
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is a conscious design choice, so you can just make Tornado not do that by subclassing `SimpleAsyncHTTPClient` and omitting that code:

```
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
from tornado.simple_httpclient import SimpleAsyncHTTPClient
from tornado.log import gen_log

class NoQueueTimeoutHTTPClient(SimpleAsyncHTTPClient):
    def fetch_impl(self, request, callback):
        key = object()

        self.queue.append((key, request, callback))
        self.waiting[key] = (request, callback, None)

        self._process_queue()

        if self.queue:
            gen_log.debug("max_clients limit reached, request queued. %d active, %d queued requests." % (len(self.active), len(self.queue)))


AsyncHTTPClient.configure(NoQueueTimeoutHTTPClient)
```

Comment: This seems right to me (and in 2019 with tornado 6.0.3 it still works), but I'd like to understand this conscious design choice before I put something like this into production. Do you have any idea why this might be there?